# Laravel 8 upsert with DB::Raw query

Tags: php, laravel, upsert, laravel-8

I am looking to use Laravel 8's native upsert function to import a batch of products. When using the package https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-upsert I could e.g. just use the following to update an image when not existing in the DB model:

```
Product::upsert(
    $values,
    $target,
    [
        'image' => DB::raw("if(`image` is null, values(`image`), `image`)"),
        // TODO: Add the other columns that should be updated.
    ]
);
```

However, this does not seem to work in Laravel 8's version of upsert. Any ideas on how I can do this?

Update:
The code I am trying currently is:

```
ShopProduct::upsert(
    $productArray,
    ['productcode'],
    [
       'image' => DB::raw("if(`image` is null, values(`image`), `image`)"),
    ]);
```

And the error I get:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1 near "values": syntax error (SQL: insert into "shop_products" ("created_at", "image", "name", "productcode", "slug", "updated_at") values (2020-11-18 21:52:03, /var/folders/y_/whnvprxj6hx514qmgwj_lb740000gn/T/cf46d09ad8845c9ff742a9045090d252.png, tempora, 6011295759374531, tempora, 2020-11-18 21:52:03), (2020-11-18 21:52:03, /var/folders/y_/whnvprxj6hx514qmgwj_lb740000gn/T/d0842fcf4ea08a4dab9f82e9456fdd36.png, qui, 4024007178334, qui, 2020-11-18 21:52:03) on conflict ("productcode") do update set "image" = if(`image` is null, values(`image`), `image`), "updated_at" = "excluded"."updated_at")
```

Comment: Have you looked at the query yet? `DB::enableQueryLog(); Product::upsert(...); dd(DB::getQueryLog());`

Comment: @Anticom the query won't log due to an error. I have updated the post with extra information.

Comment: Did you look at [the documentation for the function](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#updateorcreate) before attempting to use it? There is nothing that suggests you can do whatever you're attempting to do. "The method's third and final argument is an array of the columns that should be updated if a matching record already exists in the database."

Comment: Yes I did @miken32, but since they have implemented and tweaked https://github.com/staudenmeir/laravel-upsert, I kinda hoped this would have kept on working. I guess that's a no :(

Answer (score 1):

I used this function make things easier:

```
protected function coalesce(array $columnNames):array{
        $columns = [];
        foreach($columnNames as $value){
            $columns["{$value}"] = DB::raw("COALESCE(`{$value}`,values(`{$value}`))");
        }
        return $columns;
    }


ShopProduct::upsert(
    $productArray,
    ['productcode'],
    $this->coalesce(['image]));
```

Coalesce will take either the value of the column or the value passed, depending on the fact that is null or not